# Loading expl3: "command-already-defined" error

Tags: expl3

I am trying to import the xparse package in my main.tex to be able to use the package subfiles.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[a4paper,margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{subfiles}
```

but when I try compiling with `latex main.tex`, I get the error:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Debian) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./main.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/02/01>
Babel <3.9q> and hyphenation patterns for 3 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls
Document Class: book 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/bk10.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifvtex.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex
! !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! !
Argh, internal LaTeX3 error!

Module kernel, message name "command-already-defined":
Arguments '\@@_use_none_delimit_by_q_recursion_stop:w' and '\long macro:#1\q_@@
_recursion_stop ->'

This is one for The LaTeX3 Project: bailing out.
\__kernel_msg_error:nnxx ... Project: bailing out}
                                                  \tex_end:D 
l.2940 ...@_use_none_delimit_by_q_recursion_stop:w
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? How could the command already be defined when it's one of the first packages loaded?

Comment: This looks very odd! I take it you have TL'15 installed by your system package manager? That being the case, could you look at the top of `usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse.sty` and `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex` and find the exact release dates?

Comment: I found the release dates in the docs: 2021-06-18 for xparse and 2021-07-12 for expl3-code. (also in the code with \ProvidesExplPackage{xparse}{} and \ExplFileDate{} respectively)

Comment: That's _very_ odd: your pdfTeX and LaTeX format lines suggest you have TL'15 and matching files. Did you do something to install non-standard files in your system TeX tree?

Comment: I just installed packages from CTAN: amsmath, enumitem, etoolbox, float, l3kernel and l3packages, preprint, subfiles, was.

Comment: You have installed packages that are far newer (and not supported by) the tex system you are using. If you are using your (fairly old) debian supplied system you should update the packages using apt from a matching repository,

Comment: Locally-installed files, downloaded from CTAN or similar, shouldn't really be installed by overwriting the system tree versions. That makes it harder to back out an issue (as now), but also makes it very tricky to know how versions line up.

Comment: especially you should not copy by hand packages into the `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex` area that is maintained by the apt installed texlive packages.

Comment: I *think* what's happening is you've got badly mismatched files somewhere, which we try to guard against but this one looks very hard to diagnose. I'd start by re-installing your system TeX Live setup *then* trying to do a 'safe' local install of the packages you need.

Comment: alternatively if you want a system with the latest versions, install texlive 2021 from tug and use that rather than the debian texlive 2015 https://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html

Comment: Ok, thank you, I understand. In the end, I found an alternative.